# Python mutidimensional array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix

In python, preferably as numpy array, how can I get datastructure, exactly like this, in php:

```
$mdmat = array();
for($i=0;$i<50;$i++)
  for($x=90;$x<=510;$x+=30)
    for($y=50;$y<470;$y+=30)
       $mdmat[$i][$x][$y] = rand(0,1000);
```

So I can later change value of it's elements like this:

```
$mdmat[1][120][80]= 5;
```

I need exactly those array indexes.

Here is dump of that structure:
https://gist.github.com/acosonic/68333d286b5684e42fbdf5b28bcf9101

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are skipping over the indices in the inside loops. If you wish to retain that, then this is not really an array, but a key value pair mapping, aka dictionary.

You cannot have mutable keys in a dictionary, but can use a tuple instead.

```
import random      
mdmat = {}      
for i in range(0, 50):
    for x in range(90, 510 + 1, 30): #the +1 is to handle <= condition, range are right exclusive
        for y in range(50, 470, 30):
            mdmat[(i, x, y)] = random.randint(0,1000)
```

EDIT:
Looking at your edit, you can implement the same concept as nested dictionaries with a small tweak.

```
import random      
mdmat_root = {}      
for i in range(0, 50):
    mdmat_root[i] = {}
    for x in range(90, 510 + 1, 30): #the +1 is to handle <= condition, range are right exclusive
        mdmat_root[i][x] = {}
        for y in range(50, 470, 30):
            mdmat_root[i][x][y] = random.randint(0,1000)
```

Comment: I think the issue is this. If your understanding of arrays comes from the world of PHP, you will have to adjust to how almost every other language uses and implements arrays. (To put it nicely, PHP...messed up with calling those things arrays.)The PHP "arrays" should really not be called arrays, they are weird hybrids of what other languages call dictionaries/hashtables/associative arrays with an ugly combination of pure arrays, but they are not pure arrays.

Comment: numpy works on pure arrays, the idea being, you access values from an "index", and not from a "key/unorthodox indexes i can name or control". TL;DR No, not in the way you would want it. Does that help? @AleksandarPavić

Comment: so there can't be array of arrays in numpy?

Comment: oh no, nested arrays are always possible. It is just that you do not "customise" their indexes so to speak. you can have as many levels in an array as you like. [1] vs [[1]] vs [[[1]]] and so on, if that makes sense. @AleksandarPavić

Answer (score 0):

You can do it easily using `np.random.randint` as following where you can replace `(3,3,3)` with the desired matrix size `(i, j, k)`.

```
array = np.random.randint(0, 1000, (3,3,3))
print (array)

[[[581 956 971]
  [726  64 140]
  [891  83 666]]

 [[690 554 869]
  [325 611 908]
  [560 221 550]]

 [[878 979 488]
  [233 710 979]
  [273 462 945]]]
```

and then modify as you want using

```
array[1][2][2] = 100
print (array)

[[[581 956 971]
  [726  64 140]
  [891  83 666]]

 [[690 554 869]
  [325 611 908]
  [560 221 100]]

 [[878 979 488]
  [233 710 979]
  [273 462 945]]]
```

For your particular case, you can compute the size of the matrix as i, j, k and then use

```
i = 50
x = len(range(90, 511, 30))
y = len(range(50, 471, 30))

array = np.random.randint(0, 1000, (i,x,y))
```

You are basically using 90, 120, 150, 180 ... as indices in PHP but in python you will have to use continuous indices where 90 --> 0, 120 --> 1, 150 --> 2, 180 --> 3 and so on. Hence for `x` and `y`, you need only 15 indices (length of x and y arrays in PHP)

Comment: but my array indexes are different in PHP... And very structured, indexes are increased by 30... I'll dump my structure as gist